# can you explain the notation used in the book.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, notation, propositional-calculus

I'm reading *Kenneth H. Rosen* Book on Discrete Math, there is a question in the first section of the first chapter. There is question, which has some notation like this.

$$\bigwedge\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}\bigwedge\limits_{j=i+1}^{n}(\lnot p_i \lor \lnot p_j)$$

Can anyone give me little explanation what's meaning of it.

I have no idea what it is trying to say.

Comment: $\wedge$ is the logical operator "and". The same way you would write $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i=a_1+\ldots+a_n$ you can write $\bigwedge_{i=1}^n p_i=p_1\wedge\ldots\wedge p_n$.

Comment: I got that, but whats meaning of expression in parenthesis, can you please elaborate the whole statement.

Comment: $\neg p_i\lor \neg p_j$ means $p_i$ is false and/or $p_j$ is false.

Comment: @Yanjan.Kaf. Did you read the book from the beginning? Both notations are defined before first used.

Comment: The expression in the parenthesis is "(not $p_i$) or (not $p_j$)".

Comment: @dxiv, Thanks, I got my answer, and yes I did read it from beginning.

Comment: @Yanjan.Kaf. All of "$\;\lnot,\,\lor\;$" and "$\;\bigwedge_{j=1}^n\;$" are defined very early in the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really know the context of the statement you provided, but perhaps the best way to understand what's going on is to 'expand' the notation out. As such, we want to consider the expression as $$ \bigwedge_{i=1}^{n-1}\bigwedge_{j=i+1}^{n}(\lnot p_i \lor \lnot p_j) = \bigwedge_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(\bigwedge_{j=i+1}^{n}(\lnot p_i \lor \lnot p_j)\right). $$
So, taking the notation at its word, expand the big bracket as
$$ \bigwedge_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(\bigwedge_{j=i+1}^{n}(\lnot p_i \lor \lnot p_j)\right) = \bigwedge_{i=1}^{n-1}\bigg( (\lnot p_i \lor \lnot p_{i+1})\land (\lnot p_i \lor \lnot p_{i+2}) \land \cdots \land (\lnot p_i \lor \lnot p_{n-1}) \land (\lnot p_i \lor \lnot p_{n}) \bigg). $$
Then, if $n=10$ (why not!) we have the behemoth of an expression given as
\begin{align*} \bigg [(\lnot p_1 \lor \lnot p_{2})\land (\lnot p_1 \lor \lnot p_{3}) \land \cdots \land (\lnot p_1 \lor \lnot p_{8}) \land (\lnot p_1 \lor \lnot p_{10}) \bigg ] &\land \\
 \bigg [\hphantom{(\lnot p_2 \lor \lnot p_{3})}(\lnot p_2 \lor \lnot p_{3}) \land \cdots \land (\lnot p_2 \lor \lnot p_{8}) \land (\lnot p_2 \lor \lnot p_{10}) \bigg ] &\land
\\
&\vdots \\
\bigg [(\lnot p_8 \land \lnot p_9) \land (\lnot p_8 \land \lnot p_{10})\bigg] &\land \\
\bigg [(\lnot p_9 \land \lnot p_{10})\bigg ].\end{align*}
As you can see, we are computing all possible (not $p_i$ or not $p_j$ expressions) and 'anding' them all together. The notation is set out in such a way as to not get repeated expressions such as $(\lnot p_1 \lor \lnot p_{2})$ and $(\lnot p_2 \lor \lnot p_{1})$, which are, of course, the same thing and hence superfluous.

Comment: Thank you so much, thats what i was asking for.

Comment: No problem! To avoid getting your questions down-voted in the future, make sure you're showing some sort of working out, or some sort of attempt to understand what's going on.